# Foreach Loop not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, database, foreach

I'm trying to fetch some values from the database based on it's key I'm assigning values to a variable but it's not working as expected.
Here is my code below:

```
$sql_session = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name, option_value FROM $settings_table WHERE option_name='session' || option_name='sch_session_start'");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($sql_session);
echo "</pre>";
foreach ($sql_session as $session) {
    if($session->option_name == "session") $session =  $session->option_value;
    if($session->option_name == "sch_session_start") $session_start = $session->option_value;  //this is my line 12
}
```

The above code giving me the following error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in F:\INSTALLED\XAMPP\htdocs\SMS\wp-content\plugins\wpschoolpress\includes\wpsp-depositFeesForm.php on line 12 **(Line 12 is commented in the code above)**.

And this is how my `$sql_session` array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [option_name] => session
            [option_value] => 2018-19
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [option_name] => sch_session_start
            [option_value] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: After `$session =  $session->option_value;` the variable `$session` no longer holds the current object in the loop. Use a different variable.

Comment: ohhh. Thanks a lot. wasted hours in such a silly thing.

Comment: Also, you should use `switch/case` or `elseif`. Once you match the option name there's no need to keep testing other names.

Comment: Or just use an associative array: `$options[$session['option_name']] = $session['option_value']`.